# Using a mixin with another mixin

Tags: html, preprocessor, pug

Why does this mixin, which is within another mixin, return NaN?

```
mixin kendoui_base
    =vLibPath + "kendo/"

mixin kendoui_js(jsName)
    +include_js(+kendoui_base + "js/" + jsName)
```

kendoui_js("A") prints:

```
<script src="NaNjs/A"></script>
```

Dumping +kendoui_base without +include_js() returns the expected string.
(I just started learning Jade so I'm sorry if this is obvious.)

Answer (score 0):

Jade is interpreting your `+kendoui_base` as JavaScript syntax, which coerces `kendoui_base` function to a NaN number.

The easiest way to fix this is converting your "mixin" to a JS function:

```
- function kendoui_base() { return vLibPath + "kendo/"; }

mixin kendoui_js(jsName)
    +include_js(kendoui_base() + "js/" + jsName)
```

Remember, that mixins are used for HTML rendering, not function-like returning, etc.